# How to Install Docker on Mac Version 10.13?

Tags: docker, macos, installation, version

I know macs need version 10.15 or above to install Docker. But I want to install docker on my 10.13 mac, can you give me any advice?

（Docker officially requires at least version 10.15 or above, but my Mac can't be upgraded.）

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it can be useful for you this site, try this method who knows. Better lose than never try. You have all instructions in link below

https://www.aeoluswing.xyz/docker-for-mac/install/

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have tried the method you mentioned, but it seems to go back to the process of downloading dmg, which has been tested and is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install [Docker Desktop for MacOS](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/).
If you need Docker-Compose too, you can run `brew install docker-compose` if [Brew](https://brew.sh/index_de) isn't installed

And if that dosen`t work you can maybe virtualize an Debian based Linux...